# ionic: heic -> jpeg / png

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, heic

I'm developing an ionic app that uses GO on backend and I ran into a problem of uploading HEIC images.
Is it possible to make ionic upload photos from mobile in jpeg format (taken with ionic photo code or just taken from gallery)? Or does ionic do this automatically already?

Comment: Can you share your `camera` code?. i think you can pass jpeg option to camera to take jpg pictures.

Comment: Turnes out ionic is smart and coverts images to jpg / png / gif, so I don't need to do any conversion. My bad